# python how to generate combinations from a list of lists

Tags: python

I hope you can help me, I want to generate combinations from the following list of lists (to work as a nxn matrix):

```
   A = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]]
```

But I need that if e.g I take the first number of the first list, then as a matrix operation, remove the other elements of the column and the row of the selected element and then generate the possible combinations

For example, I choose the 1 on the first list, then the only possible combinations to generate are: (1,5,9) and (1,8,6) because the elimination the row and column.

I'm trying to build a recursive function to achieve that by removing column and row the problem is that I'm not sure about how to build the list with the combinations.

This is that I have so far:

```
list = []

def combinations(matrix):
    matrix_rows = len(matrix)
    if matrix_rows == 0:
        # Base case
        return matrix
    else:
        # Recursive case
        # Always select first row
        seq = []
        for index, a in enumerate(matrix[0]):
            E = a
            seq.append(E)
            # Remove i from row of index element a
            new_matrix = remove_row(matrix, 0)
            # Remove j from column index of element a
            new_matrix = remove_column(new_matrix, index)
            # Call again with new matrix
            combinations(new_matrix)
        list.append(seq)
    return list

def remove_row(original_matrix, element_row_index):
    new_matrix = []
    if (len(original_matrix)) >= element_row_index:
        new_matrix = original_matrix[:] 
        new_matrix.remove(original_matrix[element_row_index])
    return new_matrix

def remove_column(matrix, index):
    return [(x[0:index] + x[index + 1:]) for x in matrix]
```

With A matrix from above I'll expect to have:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]

print("Result: ", combinations(A))

Result: [[1,5,9], [1,6,8], [2,4,9], [2,6,7], [3,4,8], [3,5,7]]
```

Anyone can help me? Or give me a suggestion for a better approach

**Added:** An 4x4 example:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8],
[9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16]]

Results: [1,6,11,16], [1,6,12,15],[1,7,10,16], [1,7,12,14], [1,8,10, 15], [1,8,11, 14], ....
```

Comment: A better way in Python is to avoid the recursive function (which is relatively time-consuming in Python) and use the `itertools` module. Is this acceptable? If so, I could show you a short function using this approach.

Comment: Shure, I tried that approach (with itertools.product()), the problem is that itertools generate all the possible combinations, and I only require only the ones that met the requirements I wrote above, there's a way to do that with itertools?

Comment: What happens if there are 10 lists each with 3 elements?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that detail, this is only intended for an nxn matrix

Comment: your result is really strange. I was expecting 1,8;6 you printed 1,8,9, even if 8 & 9 are in the same row. Other triplets don't have this issue

Comment: I'm not clear on how your combination are generated, for instance, assuming there are 4x4 matrix, how many combination should there be? 4*3? 4*6? care to elaborate?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre e.g if i choose 1 in the first row, then I can't choose the other numbers from the same column(4 and 7) and row(2 and 3) then I create a new matrix removing those columns = [[5,6],[8,9]] then I choose 5, so i remove the columns again as result it gives me [9] and with that build [1,5,9] and you are right, I wrote it wrong. it's [1,6,8]

Comment: Please add a 4x4 example to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be done simply and with no recursion at all.
Basically, you want to choose all the possible permutations of `range(n)` on the rows (or columns) while going through the columns (or rows respectively) in order.
Here's one easy solution:

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

n = 3
x = np.arange(n ** 2).reshape((n, n)) + 1  # so as to fit in with your example
perms = permutations(range(n))
combinations = [list(x[range(n), p]) for p in perms]
print(combinations)
>> [[1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 7]]
```

If, however, you're not using numpy-compatible stuff, but rather a list-of-lists, here's a small tweak on the above that works just as well:

```
x = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B']]  # a "small" case so it's easy to follow
n = len(x)
index_list = range(n)
perms = permutations(index_list)
combinations = [[x[i][p[i]] for i in index_list] for p in perms]
print(combinations)
>> [[1, 'B'], ['A', 2]]
```

The above assumes you're still using "square" data. Meaning that the length of each inner list is the same length as the outer list containing them.

Hope that helps and that it does what you meant. If not please comment and I'll correct whatever's needed.  I'll leave turning this into a function to the reader ;-)
Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't depend on the matrix content at all! I used the range just to get the same matrix as you gave in the question.
And it works for the 4*4 case as well. Or any `n`.

Comment: I think it could work, the problem is that my matrix is random, not necessary in a range, for example I could have [[9, 2, 7, 8], [6, 4, 3, 7], [5, 8, 1, 8], [7, 6, 9, 4]] , I never have used numpy, it's new for me. And if instead a list of in I have an list of tuples, for example [(1, "A"), (6, "B")] its possible to use the same library?

Comment: @ElrosRomeo BTW, I recommend  using numpy when suitable. The first solution is nicer in my opinion because indexing is easier with numpy. And the list-of-lists [[9, 2, 7, 8], [6, 4, 3, 7], [5, 8, 1, 8], [7, 6, 9, 4]] can just as easily be made a np.array([[9, 2, 7, 8], [6, 4, 3, 7], [5, 8, 1, 8], [7, 6, 9, 4]]).